# Cross-compilation broke when transitioning from Ubuntu 20 to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c++, qt, linker, cross-compiling

Cross-compilation was working perfectly fine using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` (with Kits set up in QT Creator on a specially compiled version of Qt 5.12.3 for our device) in Ubuntu 20.04. But the devil prompted me to upgrade to 22.04, and that led to the aforementioned issue.

Here's what the compiler/linker dumped out:

```
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '_dl_make_stack_executable@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_dlclose@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__libc_dlopen_mode@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_longjmp@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_dl_error_tsd@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_vfork@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_allocate_rtsig_private@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__clock_getres@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_thread_freeres@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__clock_getcpuclockid@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to '_dl_addr@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_pthread_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_current_sigrtmin_private@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to '_dl_sym@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__clock_nanosleep@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__libc_dlsym@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to '__libc_current_sigrtmax_private@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2: undefined reference to '_dl_vsym@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: /home/asianirish/img/armbian/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1: undefined reference to '__clock_settime@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(Sysroot is here: `/home/asianirish/img/armbian`)

Why would undefined references appear where everything used to work before? What to do? I can't wrap my head around it!